# Why is it still day in Mumbai at 6:47 PM?

Tags: earth-rotation, sun

I captured this news channel picture on Sept 11 2018 from India.

[image]

We can clear see It is live telecast from Mumbai, but it is still day time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This image from https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/india/mumbai shows that daylight ended at 6:44, so 6:47 was three minutes into civil twilight and pretty much close to daylight.

Notice the orange light in the back - I'm assuming that this is a [street lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp), which are only turned on at twilight.

Most likely the image appears relatively bright because of camera settings, not because it is full daylight outside.

Answer (score 2):

Sundown in Mumbai is 18:47 today... I guess it is the problem of a huge country having only one time zone (same for China)... Mumbai is at the western coast and the Indian Standard Time is based on Kolkata (which is far more east)... Sundown in Kolkata in around 17:40...

Answer (score 1):

You may be surprised to hear this, but in my home country Germany, sunset was around 10pm in the summer. Where I now live, in Colorado, sunset was today at 7:03pm. It all depends on how far east or west you are in your current time zone, and how far north/south you are relative to where the sun currently circles the Earth.